# how to get overwritten value via environment value when reading config as map using config.getProperty method in grails6

Tags: grails

I have configuration defined in application.yml as

```
storage:
  local:
    container: "/var/optimus"
```

When I run the application, I have set the environment variable:

STORAGE_LOCAL_CONTAINER: "/Users/test/mount"

Now in my spring/resources.groovy file, when reading config as map

```
grailsApplication.config.getProperty('storage.local', Map)
```

I get map with container value as **"/var/optimus"**. This should have returned **"/Users/test/mount"** as container value instead!

However when I read the config as :

```
grailsApplication.config.getProperty('storage.local.container')
```

I get the correct config value **"/Users/test/mount"**.

How to read application config as a map so as to get overwritten values as well? I need to read the config as a map because I have to pass it to a service because it contains other config within the "local" config. The code snippet was just to elaborate on the issue.

Using:

- grails 6
- java 17